# ¿Cómo recorrer un arreglo multidimensional autogenerado a través de $_POST en PHP?

Tags: php, post, array

Tengo el siguiente formulario que contiene inputs que se clonan a través de botones, los botones de los signos más (+) y menos (-), clonan y eliminan respectivamente los input de label “marca y valor” y el botón de agregar clona todo el conjunto incluyendo el input de label “producto”.

He colocado nombres a los inputs de tal manera que sean del tipo array, la condición es que “producto” sea un arreglo que contenga a “marca y valor”.

```js
$(function(){
            $(document).on('click',"#agregartablauno" , function(){                
            $("#tablauno tbody tr:eq()").clone()
                .append('<td class="eliminartablauno"><input type="button" value="ELIMINAR"/></td>')
                .appendTo("#tablauno");         
            });

            $(document).on("click",".eliminartablauno",function(){
            var parent = $(this).parent();
            $(parent).remove();
            });

            $(this).on('click', ".agregartablados" , function(){                
            $(".tablados tbody tr:eq()").clone()
                .append('<td class="eliminartablados"><input type="button" value="-"/></td>')
                .appendTo(".tablados");         
            });

            $(document).on("click",".eliminartablados",function(){
            var parent = $(this).parent();
            $(parent).remove();
            });
        });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head><title>I</title>
    <script>
    </script>
</head>
<body><center>
<form method="POST" action="ClonProducto1.php">    
   <table id="tablauno" align="center" >
     <tr>
       <td>
        ARTICULO <input type="text" name="form[txtarticulo][nombre]" size=32 />
       </td>                                         
       <td>
        <table class="tablados">
            <thead>
              <tr>
                 <td>MARCA</td>
                 <td>VALOR</td>
              </tr>
             </thead>
             <tbody>
               <tr id="filas-base">
                  <td><input id="txtmarca" name="form[txtarticulo][txtmarca]" type="text" /></td>
                  <td><input id="txtvalor" name="form[txtarticulo][txtvalor]" type="text" /></td> 
               </tr>
              </tbody>
        </table> 
        <input class="agregartablados" type="button" value="+" /> 
      </td>            
    </tr>
   </table>
   <input id="agregartablauno" type="button" value="AGREGAR"> <br><br>
<input name="enviar" type="submit" value=" Enviar ">
</form>  
</center></body>
</html>
```

Al introducir los valores dentro de los inputs, por ejemplo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y al hacer en mi archivo PHP un  print_r($_POST); para observar si mi array esta dispuesto correctamente y al rrecorrerlo con FOREACH y visualizarlo, obtengo que cuando hay solamente un input por cada propiedad, el array es correcto.

```html
Array ( [form] => Array ( [txtarticulo] => Array ( [nombre] => art_1 [txtmarca] => mar_1 [txtvalor] => val_1 ) ) [enviar] => Enviar ) 
art_1, mar_1, val_1
```

Pero cuando hay más de un (1) input en el formulario, no hace el recorrido al array, solo tiene en cuenta el ultimo input para formar el arreglo.
Este es el código que utilizo en el archivo PHP.

```html
<?php 
print_r($_POST);
foreach( $_REQUEST['form'] as $k => $c ) {
    $c1=implode(', ',$c);
    echo "<br>".$c1."<br>";   }
¿>
```

Por ejemplo para este caso:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El arreglo queda así al realizar un  print_r($):

```
Array ( 
[form] => Array ( 
    [txtarticulo] => Array ( 
        [nombre] => Array ( 
            [0] => art1 [1] => art2 ) 
        [txtmarca] => Array ( 
            [0] => mar11 [1] => mar21 [2] => mar22 ) 
        [txtvalor] => Array ( 
            [0] => val11 [1] => val21 [2] => val22 ) 
                            ) 
                ) 
[enviar] => Enviar 
)
```

Pero quiero que quede de la siguiente manera:

```
Array ( 
[form] => Array ( 
    [txtarticulo] => Array (            
        [nombre] => Array (
            [0] => $art1= Array ( 
                            [txtmarca] => ("mar11")
                            [txtvalor] => ("val1")
                                )
            [1] => $art2= Array ( 
                            [txtmarca] => ("mar21","mar22")
                            [txtvalor] => ("val1", "val22")
                                )
                            ) 
                ) 
[enviar] => Enviar 
)
```

Comment: `foreach( $_REQUEST['form'] as $k => $c ) {
    echo "<br>".$c."<br>";   }` te imprimirá cada valor del array. Y si haces: `foreach( $_REQUEST['form'] as $k => $c ) {
    echo "<br>".$k.": ".$c."<br>";   }` te imprimirá las llaves y los valores al lado.

Comment: Si lo que hago con el foreach es imprimir solo el valor del array la llave no necesito que se imprima, pero es necesario usar el implode para convertir un arreglo a cadena, tambien se puede imprimir en pantalla con print_r($) directamente, pero ese no es el problema que tengo, el problema es que cuando clono los inputs siempre al hacer el rrecorrido con el foreach me imprime el arreglo con el ultimo valor, lo ideal seria que se visualizen todos los elementos del arreglo articulo con su nombre, marca y valor, todos, no solamente los valores de un solo input si no de los input creados.

Answer (score 1):

**Actualización**

Si lo que quieres es que la información de cada artículo se mantenga a parte, puedes hacer que los nombres de los campos sean siempre diferentes pero tengan la misma raíz por cada fila. Es decir, algo así:

```
form[txtarticulo1][nombre]
form[txtarticulo1][txtmarca]
form[txtarticulo1][txtvalor]
form[txtarticulo2][nombre]
form[txtarticulo2][txtmarca]
form[txtarticulo2][txtvalor]
```

En ese caso, podrías recorrer la información de esta manera:

```
<?php
$articulos = $_REQUEST['form'];
foreach($articulos as $articulo){
  echo $articulo['nombre'];
  echo $articulo['txtmarca'];
  echo $articulo['txtvalor'];
}
?>
```

**Respuesta original**

El problema es que los nombres que le estás dando a los campos hacen que se sobreescriba la información, en lugar de insertar cada nuevo valor cómo una posición en el arreglo. Lo que debes hacer es poner corchetes abriendo y cerrando al final del nombre de cada elemento, así:

```
form[txtarticulo][nombre][]
```

El otro problema que encontrarás luego, es que los artículos no llegan separados por arreglo sino que cada dato (nombre, txtmarca y txtvalor) tiene su propio arreglo. Así que deberías cambiar el `foreach` por algo cómo:

```
<?php
$articulo = $_REQUEST['form']['txtarticulo'];
foreach($articulo['nombre'] as $llave => $valor){
  echo $articulo['nombre'][$llave];
  echo $articulo['txtmarca'][$llave];
  echo $articulo['txtvalor'][$llave];
}
?>
```

Comment: Si muy bien THANK´S lo que me señalaste, realice la corrección, pero aún sigo con el problema de autogenerar el arreglo, cada input de “articulo”, tiene sus propios valores de “marca y valor”, pero al recorrer el arreglo se está imprimiendo o almacenando todas las “marcas” en un solo arreglo, así como el “valor” en un solo arreglo sin realizar la diferenciación con respecto para cada “articulo”, la condición es que “articulo” sea un arreglo que contenga a “marca y valor”, pero cada arreglo “articulo” contiene distintos arreglos de marca y valor.

Comment: Sí, así es cómo sucede por cómo se envían las variables. El problema es que técnicamente le estás diciendo a PHP que cada uno de ellos forma parte de un arreglo independiente. Lo que podrías hacer sería cambiar los nombres a medida que los agregas con Javascript, para que todos vayan en un arreglo independiente. Actualicé mi respuesta para que te hagas una idea

Answer (score 0):

Ya que estás obligando al usuario a tener javascript activo para poder usar los botones "+", "-" y "Agregar", yo capturaría el *submit* del formulario y codificaría todo como una cadena JSON que pasaría al servidor en una única variable.

Para ello, puedes crear un `<input type="hidden">` y assignable el valor JSON durante el evento.

De esta manera recorrerás el arreglo que tú mismo hayas creado en el javascript, no lo que te imponga el servidor.